# how to add a new port in existing XML Generator transformation in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to add a new port into an existing mapping **XML Generator transformation**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the below steps to add a new port in xml generator.

1. Go to edit transformation
2. In the Midstream XML Generator tab, add a pass-through port
3. Then open the XML Editor on the top right corner
4. Right-click the Root View and select Add Reference Port
5. This will list the pass-through port that you created in Step 1. Then select the added element you want.
6. Save and exit. The added pass-through port will be displayed in the XML generator.